# Variable creation, length of str, and using the length property

Tags: javascript

```
function exerciseThree (str) {

 // In this exercise, you will be given a variable, it will be called: str

 // On the next line create a variable called 'length'
 // and using the length property assign the new variable to the length of str    

  // Please write your answer in the line above.
  return length;
}
```

This is a question from my intro to JavaScript assignment. I'm not understanding what the exercise is asking of me.

The `length` property returns the length of a string (number of characters).
The exercise tells me I'm given a variable called `str`

Therefore:

```
var str = "";

str.length; //? I'm so lost.
```

So I know I'm definitely seeing this the wrong way. I would be grateful if someone could explain the exercise and its purpose (i.e. are they actually looking for `str.length;`?).

Comment: `str` is passed in the `argument` of the funtion. So it says `you . will be given a variable`. The it says `create a variable called length` so, you have to declare `var length = str.length` . and then `return` it.

Answer (score 0):

You're given the variable (it's passed as a parameter into the function) so you don't have to make one - just set `length` to `str.length`:

```js
function exerciseThree (str) {
  var length = str.length;
  return length;
}

console.log("'One' is " + exerciseThree("One") + " characters long");
console.log("'Hello, World!' is " + exerciseThree("Hello, World!") + " characters long");
```